# Temp mount works but permanent mount errors - Raspberry Pi to Windows

Tags: windows, mount, fstab

I am trying to access a shared drive on a Windows server from a Raspberry Pi 3.

My temporary mount works - `sudo mount //192.168.1.10/Files /home/pi/Files -o username=Myname,password=Mypassword` - I can browse the folder and see all the files.

If I add a line to `/etc/fstab` - `//192.168.1.10/Files /home/pi/Files cifs username=Myname,password=Mypassword,iocharset-utf8,sec=ntlm,users 0 0`

I get a Mount Error(22) but I cannot see what is wrong.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

After a little trial and error the following appears to work

`//192.168.1.10/Files /home/pi/Files cifs username=Myname,password=Mypassword,users`

Comment: Vote your answer as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This ***may be*** the same issue I've had in the past. It's poorly documented, and IMHO **buggy**. I wasted a week on this ~ 3 years ago - including the bug reports submitted to Raspberry Pi, and then to Debian which were ignored.

Anyway - in my case the issue was unique to the software that handles SMB/CIFS mounts (network drives typically) from `fstab`. As it turns out, there are several ***versions of SMB***; you can see a list of these in `man mount.cifs`. And - at least in my case - getting the correct version was crucial to a successful mount (consummation? :).

It's still painful to recall (*mostly due to how my bug report was handled*), and AFAIK it's still buggy. The point of this post is only my effort to raise awareness that when it comes to SMB mounts - ***version matters***.

Here's the `fstab` specification that I'm still using; note the *placement* of the `vers=xx` option.

```
//NetgearNAS-3/backup /mnt/NetgearNAS-3/backup cifs rw,username=seamus,password=XXXXXXXX,nofail,vers=1.0 0 0
```

You may be wondering how to determine the SMB protocol version (I did). On a Windows machine, that is said to be available from the "Power Shell" using the command: `Get-SmbConnection`. On a Linux server (Samba), this should work: `sudo smbstatus`. If you're using a network appliance (as I am) as a SMB/CIFS file server, you may have to resort to *trial-and-error*.